# How to Circumvent Anaconda GCC Compiler?

Tags: gcc, anaconda

I upgraded to Anaconda 5 which comes with its own compiler toolset, i.e. does not use the OS-provided compilers anymore, see https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/compiler-tools.html. However, I need to use a different GCC compiler (since a library is apparently not available), but have been unsuccessful to set the correct path(s) and am not sure about the descriptions at the above link.

In short, how can I force the use of a certain (let's say OS-provided) gcc compiler when running a setup.py script within an Anaconda environment? Alternatively, how can I (temporarily) circumvent setting the path to the Anaconda compilers when activating an environment?

Comment: I'd would edit any of these, but the Conda `*-compiler` packages place activation scripts in `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/`. You could look through those to see what environment variables they manipulate. You likely need to manipulate those same variables to direct away from their compiler.

Comment: I bungled that one. Meant to say "I wouldn't edit any of these, but...". Anyway, temporarily hiding them as you did sounds good. Just be aware of the corresponding `deactivate.d/` scripts as well.

Comment: I understood what you meant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [merv's helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64289376/how-to-circumvent-anaconda-gcc-compiler#comment113697340_64289376), I (temporarily) removed the contents of the bash script `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-gcc_linux-64.sh`, re-activated the anaconda environment and successfully compiled with the paths set in the OS.

Edit: As added [here by merv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64289376/how-to-circumvent-anaconda-gcc-compiler#comment113703580_64289376), `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/deactivate.d/deactivate-gcc_linux-64.sh` might also be helpful.